# Polymorphism and Dynamic biniding not possible while mutiple inheritence

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, dynamic-binding

I don't understand why it is so? I found it while reading from [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/multiple_inheritance.html). It doesn't explain why it is and I could not find anything on google.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not what it says.

It says that if you try to solve the problems  multiple inheritance presents by, instead of inheriting, making those classes members of your class, you lose the power of polymorphism and Dynamic binding.